# htaccess code for maintenance page redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I set up a maintenance page that I could enable through an htaccess file. The html file is located in a folder called "maintenance".

The html file has some images in it. However, visitors to the page see no images, even though I added a `RewriteCond` line to (theoretically) allow them.

If I try to visit the URL of an image file in the browser directly, it redirects to the maintenance.htm page. I do not want image files to be redirected.

Am I missing something?

```
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.111.111.111$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance/maintenance\.htm$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance/maintenance.htm [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Just in case I didn't downvote, but don't quite get what you want. ¿The problem is visitors are always redirected to the maintenance page, even when the rules are not supposed to do it?

Comment: The problem is that images are *also* redirecting. I *don't* want images redirected.

Comment: What's the URL of one of the images? These rules work fine for me.

Comment: OK. Try to add some requested and substitution URL examples. Those are imposible to guess. `http://mydomain.com/directory/image.gif` goes to `http://mydomain.com/maintenance/maintenance/` but I want it to go to http://...., for example.

Comment: `http://mydomain.com/login.php` should redirect to `http://mydomain.com/maintenance/maintenance.htm`. `http://mydomain.com/images/mylogo.jpg` should remain unchanged. `http://mydomain.com/maintenance/construction.jpg` should remain unchanged. The problem is that *everything* is redirecting to `http://mydomain.com/maintenance/maintenance.htm`--including the jpg files.

Comment: Check this link http://www.phphunger.com/2013/05/how-to-redirect-visitors-to-maintenance.html#.UZsR6KKnzQI

Comment: You should select Felipe's answer as correct.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will work:

```bsh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
  # RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.111.111.111$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance/maintenance\.htm$ 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|ico)$ 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /maintenance/maintenance.htm [L]
</IfModule>
```

I added a condition to confirm the rewrite module is active before procesing the rule. The question rule and conditions are not modified.

This rule was tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance/maintenance\.htm$ [NC]` is necessary to prevent an endless loop. With the rules as shown, requests to /maintenance/maintenance.html will be redirected to themselves.

Comment: It is a valid flag and I tested the rules so I have no idea of what's the problem. Sorry. Are you placing the `RewriteEngine on` instruction in the first line, because in your example is missing

Comment: Yes, `RewriteEngine on` is at the top of the htaccess file.

Comment: If I remove the space `[NC,OR]`, the error in chrome reads as `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.`. If I add the space `[NC, OR]`, I get an error 500.

Comment: @ForceFlow Enclosed the rule in a condition to try to detect the problem. It works fine in the test server with the link in my answer, in case you want to try it.